# Windows media center Extender Error

Tags: windows, windows-media-center, xbox360, xbox-video

I recently brought a new computer and when i try to link my Xbox 360 to my external hard drive using windows media centers extender option (what everyone uses) but i get this error after 2 steps and it wont connect no matter what i do.

Things i have also tried: disabling all my firewalls but it still didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.
Thanks,
Antp

Comment: well, when upgrading the computer the old HDD is now used as a secondary HDD, this HHD had the settings to connect to the Xbox 360 media centre and it worked fine. now with the new hardware I encounter configuration errors every time.

Comment: about the error, its just a normal configuration error and I wouldn't know were to find a detailed log of whats going on.

Comment: ANY IDEAS ANYONE?????

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just do a clean install of windows, there is no way do do this with the externder on windows 7 ultimate.

Comment: Alright.... not the answer i wanted but its the only one i got, so ill have to be doing it.

Comment: @Antp - If its not the answer you wanted, why accept it?

Comment: Well i asked it 3 months ago and i still haven't got an answer, is if its the only way ill do it.